# Instantiate a JavaScript object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, instantiation

I tried to instantiate a javascript object in a typescript file, basically in an Angular Application but there is an error as object is not defined.

My JavaScript file:

```
    import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

    export default class Cursor extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(el) {}
    //some methods
}
```

My typescript file
**First alternative :**

```
declare var Cursor:any;
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

   ngOnInit(): void {
    const cursor = new Cursor();
    console.log(cursor.emit('enter'))
   }
}
```

=>  ERROR ReferenceError: Cursor is not defined

**Second alternative (importing js file)**

```
import Cursor from '../utils/js/cursor';
   export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    
       ngOnInit(): void {
        const cursor = new Cursor();
        console.log(cursor.emit('enter'))
       }
    }
```

=> Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'Cursor'.
In that case there is an inheritance problem with class Cursor extending EventEmitter

Can someone give me an hand with that problem ?
Thanks

Comment: On more details: EventEmitter is located in my node_module/@types/node/events.d.ts

Comment: You probably need to use the Angular's event emitter, not the one from Node.js

Comment: If I use Angular's event emitter, I have error on my javascript file because there are some method from 'events'